# pass android function that uses a param

Tags: java, android, callable

I've been using `Callable`, but now I need the function to use a param in the `call` method. I get that this isn't a capability of `call` so how can I do this?

What I currently have (wrong):

```
AsyncTask async = new MyAsyncTask();
async.finished(new Callable(param) {
    // the function called during async.onPostExecute;
    doSomething(param);
});
async.execute(url);
```

MyAsyncTask:

```
...
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)  {
    //super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result != null) {
        try {
            this._finished.call(result); // not valid because call accepts no params
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void finished(Callable<Void> func) {
    this._finished = func;
}
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make `param` a final variable, you can just refer to it from within the `Callable`:

```
final String param = ...;
async.finished(new Callable() {
    // the function called during async.onPostExecute;
    doSomething(param);
});
```

You'll have to do this when you *create* the `Callable` though - you can't give it the value later. If you need that for some reason, you'll have to basically use shared state - some "holder" which the `Callable` has access to, and which can have the value set into it before the `Callable` executes. That could probably just be the `MyAsyncTask` itself:

```
final MyAsyncTask async = new MyAsyncTask();
async.finished(new Callable() {
    // the function called during async.onPostExecute;
    doSomething(async.getResult());
});
async.execute(url);
```

Then:

```
private JSONObject result;
public JSONObject getResult() {
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)  {
    this.result = result;
    if(result != null) {
        try {
            this._finished.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG it's ***Jon Skeet*** aka the *LeBron James* of `SOF`. It took me a second to get what you were doing with the code, but now that I get it - it works like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new class like this

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public abstract class ParamCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
    public String Member; // you can add what you want here, ints, bools, etc.
}
```

Then all you have to do is

```
ParamCallable<YourType> func = new ParamCallable<YourType>() {
    public YourType call() {
        // Do stuff.
        // Reference Member or whatever other members that you added here.
        return YourType;
    }
}
```

and then when you call it jest set your data and call call()

```
func.Member = value;
func.call();
```